# UIWebView Xhmtl parse error but safari don't

Tags: iphone, safari, uiwebview

I have an application showing standard html pages. I use UIWebView for html. When using safari for pages no problem. When I use uiwebview the page does not load.

Error message(UIWebView)

```
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 230 at column 33: AttValue: " or ' expected
```

Below is rendering of the page up to the first error

Different page different xhtml error.

---

I realased that ipad simulator load page properly too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue. 
I resolved it by explicitly setting the MIME type of the page to be "text/html".
Otherwise it was being parsed in the UIWebview as xhtml.

eg in ASP.NET in your masterpage set

```
<% Response.ContentType = "text/html"; %>
```

Also check your `<!DOCTYPE>` isn't claiming to be xhtml.