# UIWebView shows error when webpage is loaded, Safari shows perfectly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, uiwebview

The problem is that the website doesn't fully load in a UIWebView, but it loads normally in Safari.

This is the error I get when loading the website in a UIWebView:

> Warning:
>   cos_before_render(/home/user/ctown/doc_wbn//../sys/swt/www.westspringsec.moe.edu.sg.mob)
>   [function.cos-before-render]: failed
>   to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   /home/user/ctown/cti_bin/wbn/cos_init.inc
>   on line 731
>
> Warning: cos_before_render()
>   [function.include]: Failed opening
>   '/home/user/ctown/doc_wbn//../sys/swt/www.westspringsec.moe.edu.sg.mob'
>   for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/home/user/ctown/cti_bin/phplot:/usr/local/lib/php')
>   in
>   /home/user/ctown/cti_bin/wbn/cos_init.inc
>   on line 731
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined
>   function: json_encode() in
>   /home/user/ctown/cti_bin/wbn/cos_init.inc
>   on line 737

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.westspringsec.moe.edu.sg";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [Webview loadRequest:requestObj];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I tried the question linked below, however I can't modify the backend of the website!

[UIWebView Xhmtl parse error but safari don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701598/uiwebview-xhmtl-parse-error-but-safari-dont)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIWebView and Safari does not have the same user agent.

Comment: okay thanks , but what does user agent exactly means ? i always see it !

Answer (score 3):

The error is not within your code! The UIWebView, especially from within the simulator uses a user agent something like this:

Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone Simulator; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/8C134

When you call the url provided it results in the error you are seeing. It's a server side error.

You can alter your user agent by using this code, put it somewhere in the startup phase of your app so it's only set once:

```
NSDictionary *dictionnary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Safari/528.16", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionnary];
[dictionnary release];
```

With this I was able to open your page. It looks like the site returns different markup for the iphone, so the result with the code above will show the website, which is a bit large for the small display.

Comment: hi nick , do i put this into the .h .m file of the view controller or my app delegate?

Comment: You can put that in your app delegate. It has to be set only once.

Comment: I just wanted to add my experience here. I was receiving an error -999 on many sites (such as Groupon) after the UIWebView went through 3 or 4 redirects. Changing the user agent to something less valid, as in the example, caused the NON-mobile version of Groupon to load correctly. I didn't really want the non-mobile version, but at least it loaded. I'm still searching for a real fix for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This answer won't fix your issue (see Nick's answer), but you should put `[super viewDidLoad];` before you do anything else. So:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.westspringsec.moe.edu.sg";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [Webview loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```