# How to tell when Safari is done loading a webpage

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to track when Safari is done loading a page request.  I call Safari to open using this code:

```
// Open Safari
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/" description]]];
```

But, since my app goes to the background, it may be [suspended (and not able to execute code)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html).  Is this even possible to do within Xcode 4?

**EDIT**

The reason why I am doing this is because [the UIWebView and Safari are not running at the same level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496505/differences-between-uiwebview-and-mobile-safari) and I want to do some performance related testing on some websites.

Comment: Are you targeting AppStore or a jailbroken device? I have a solution for jailbroken devices.

Comment: AppStore.  But if you could post the jailbroken one that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in general.

One thing you could do is from the page to be loaded, do a redirect to your application's URL scheme, which will launch your app. For more information on this matter, look at the `-[UIApplicationDelegate application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:]` method.

I don't think your application can reject the activation through such an URL scheme, so this means that your application will become active. Maybe the return value of the above method (which is a boolean) can be used, you'll have to test that.

This method also assumes that you have access to the page you're opening, so that you can add the redirect.

Comment: I'm testing pages that are not exactly mine... is there anyway to insert Javascript into the Safari webpage to do a re-direct back to my app when it is done loading?

Comment: I guess there isn't, because then you are essentially doing an XSS attack.

Comment: This makes sense from a security stand-point.... I'm probably thinking there isn't a way either because of this.

Comment: So sadly, you'll then have to wait for Apple to update `UIWebView` to the fast Javascript engine used in Mobile Safari. Maybe iOS6? Just two weeks until WWDC!

Answer (score 2):

So, if you'd like to see how I did it for jailbroken iOS (instead of the quite boring "Not possible"): I basically hooked safari to get access to the particular method that is called when the page has finished loaing. Using MobileSubstrate (filter for com.apple.mobilesafari when injecting your dynamic library):

```
#import <substrate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

/* Some globals */
static IMP _orig_1, _orig_2;
static id tabController;

id _mod_1(id __self, SEL __cmd, CGRect frame, id tabDocument);
void _mod_2(id __self, SEL __cmd, id doc, BOOL error);


/* The library constructor */
__attribute__((constructor))
static void init()
{
    Class tabClass;

    tabClass = objc_getClass("TabController");

    MSHookMessageEx(tabClass, @selector(initWithFrame:tabDocument:),    
        (IMP)_mod_1, &_orig_1);
    MSHookMessageEx(tabClass, @selector(tabDocument:didFinishLoadingWithError:),
        (IMP)_mod_2, &_orig_2);
}


/* This hook merely captures the TabController of Safari. */
id _mod_1(id __self, SEL __cmd, CGRect frame, id tabDocument)
{
    __self = _orig_1(__self, __cmd, frame, tabDocument);
    tabController = __self;
    return __self;
}

/* This is called when the page loading is done */
void _mod_2(id __self, SEL __cmd, id doc, BOOL error)
{
    /* Make sure you always call the original method */
    _orig_2(__self, __cmd, doc, error);

    /* then do what you want */
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for posting this!

Comment: No problem. Hope it'll be useful one day.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. You can do this if you open the link in a UIWebView within your own application, however.