# UIWebView and Safari comparison

Tags: ios, uiwebview, mobile-safari

1. Does UIWebView use the same JavaScript engine as Mobile Safari?
2. Also, does UIWebView support all HTML5 features like Mobile Safari does? I am specifically concerned about Web SQL and Web Workers
3. If I have an app which is written purely in HTML and JS, should I wrap it up in a UIWebView  or should I have it open in Mobile Safari
4. Are pure HTML and JS apps accepted on the Apple store?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Does UIWebView use the same JavaScript engine as Mobile Safari?

UIWebView does not have the Nitro Javascript engine, so it executes JS slower than Mobile Safari. So it's not the same.

> Also, does UIWebView support all HTML5 features like Mobile Safari does? I am specifically concerned about Web SQL and Web Workers

Not sure about this one. Probably not. At least UIWebView is a bit more strict than Safari on certain features. Example: when setting a width/height style through JS, you need to add 'px' behind the number, while Mobile Safari does not require that.

> If I have an app which is written purely in HTML and JS, should I wrap it up in a UIWebView or should I have it open in Mobile Safari

If you want to release the app on the App Store, you will have to wrap it. If not, you don't really have to.

> Are pure HTML and JS apps accepted on the Apple store?

If you wrap it, yes. But it has some limitations, as James Webster wrote.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496505/differences-between-uiwebview-and-mobile-safari) here on SO for more information on the differences between UIWebView and Safari.

Comment: Note that if you're developing for iOS 8 or later then you can use `WKWebView` which does have the same JavaScript engine as Safari and other improvements. More info here: http://nshipster.com/wkwebkit/

Answer (score 2):

I can only really provide insight to part 4 of your question with these snippets:

There are a few guidelines in the [App Store Review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) (requires login) that mention "web"

> 2.12 Apps that are not very useful, **are simply web sites bundled as apps**, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected
>
> 2.17 Apps that browse the web must use the iOS WebKit framework and WebKit Javascript
>
> 12.3 Apps that are simply web clippings, content aggregators, or a collection of links, may be rejected