# Good way to profile page load time from mobile browsers

Tags: android, ios, browser, profiler

I want to compare page load time between mobile browsers (such as iOS Safari, Android browser). I can't find profiling tools for these mobile browsers.

Do you have any good idea?

One possible option I think now is using UIWebView of iOS and WebView of Android to implement simple applications which can detect page loading events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of limitation of UIWebView ([UIWebView and Safari comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648184/uiwebview-and-safari-comparison)), for iOS using UIWebView to create simple app to profile page loading time is not good idea.

Instead of this, I can use web inspector for mobile Safari browser. Please see [this Apple document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006515-SW11).

For Android, WebView could be a choice to profile page loading time by overriding [WebViewCient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html)'s event methods. I couldn't find iOS like profiling tool for Android browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Remote Debugging on Android with Chrome.Its quite easy .