# Is chrome for iPad same as the desktop version?

Tags: ios, ipad, google-chrome

I frequently use the http://caniuse.com/ lists to check browser compatibility.

You have "Chrome" and "Chrome for Android" columns, but no "Chrome for iOS".

So is the iOS version identical to the desktop Chrome? Or Android Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Chrome on iOS actually use UIWebView because of Apple's restrictions.

Comment: So that would mean the "iOS safari" column will serve for both Safari and Chrome? And, does it use the Nitro engine or the v8 one?

Comment: Quick answer ... Chrome for iOS is pretty much like a "slower" Safari for iOS. UIWebView does not use Nitro  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648184/uiwebview-and-safari-comparison

Answer (score 1):

The underlying engine for Chrome for IOS is the standard UIWebView (like what safari for ios uses), not the one for the desktop.