# Do the Facebook and Twitter mobile apps use the Safari browser?

Tags: ios, twitter, browser, facebook-apps

Apps on iOS or Android devices, do the built-in browsers (like the Facebook & Twitter app) use the OS's browser or do the apps use their own? For instance, if my iOS's main browser is Safari, is it then also used by the apps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In iOS I think they use the UIWebView class to display a generic web content.
There are also frameworks that allow an application to navigate the web but I don't think they're correlate in any way with Safari.

For the Android part, I guess it's the same..

Comment: So it could really be that a website is perfectly working in Safari/Chrome and Android mobile browsers, but not in the apps' built-in browsers? That would be a pain in the ass because developers would have to check if everything's working in a lot of built-in browsers of a lot of apps then…? Holy Moly. But maybe they're just some webkit?

Comment: The UIWebView class isn't correlated with Safari: in other words when an app accesses the web, Safari isn't called in any way. But this doesn't mean that UiWebView displays web content incorrettly: I guess also Safari uses an UIWebView to display web content.

Comment: Ok, it seems that almost only the JS Nitro engine is missing, therefore making heavy JS slower than in Safari – as from what I understand. I guess rendering will be the same. I hope.
Found something here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648184/uiwebview-and-safari-comparison

Answer (score 0):

No. The apps use their own.....

Comment: Although this is correct as far as I am aware, it's probably worth including a reference to an official source. Otherwise this isn't robust enough to warrant being posted as an answer.

Comment: Official documentation or a link would be very helpful