# Corona SDK native WebView browsers

Tags: ios, coronasdk

What browser is using Corona SDK for the native WebView?

I presume for iOS it is using an Objective C WebView which should use Safari, and for Android it's using Chrome, but I haven't been able to find any reference to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know abut Android But iOS UIWebView is not safari that is sure.

You can rad some difference here : [UIWebView and Safari comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648184/uiwebview-and-safari-comparison)

One more article about this : [Apple confirms some WebKit optimizations unavailable to iOS Apps](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/03/18/apple-confirms-some-webkit-optimizations-unavailable-to-ios-apps/)

iOS 8 give new WebView named [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/index.html) One good article about this is here : [NSHipster : WKWeb​View](http://nshipster.com/wkwebkit/)

But I don't know that Corona is going to use WKWebView or not.