# Swift UIWebview consumes 101% of the cpu and the app crashes

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uiwebview

I'm working on a swift app that contains a UIWebView and the site that it shows is kinda big and it has a lot of pictures and javascript, when I test it on a virtual device, it works. but on a real Iphone or Ipad it crashes after a couple of seconds, Xcode shows me the memory usage goes around 50 mb and the cpu usage goes up until 101% and the app crashes.

Is there a way to fix this without editing the website?

Comment: Probably not. If your website is loaded with JS, I bet this is causing your memory leap.

Comment: Check your webview delegate methods. `webViewDidLoad` should be called constantly. Share you code you've tried.

Comment: GIJOW.. yup the site's content uses JS, but how come? a huge company like apple can't make a web view that handles JS smoothly?

Comment: Krunal.. I didn't use webViewDidLoad at all, this is the code that contains the web view

 var ViewURL = URL(string: "example.com")

and in the view did load:

 let ViewURLRequest = URLRequest (url: ViewURL!)
        webView.loadRequest(ViewURLRequest)

Comment: Have you tried viewing the website in Safari on an iPhone or iPad?

Comment: @paulvs .. Yes I did, and It works fine on safari

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the URL?

Comment: here's the website's link in case anyone wants to test http://doctor-store.com/

Comment: [`UIWebView` != mobile Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648184/uiwebview-and-safari-comparison). If you are targeting iOS 8 and later, `WKWebView` will offer much better Javascript performance. The only annoyance is that you can't drag a `WKWebView` into your storyboard in Interface Builder but this has been fixed as of Xcode 9 Beta 4

Comment: I agree with Code Different. You will probably be happier once you start using WKWebview rather than UIWebView. It's easy to add it via code, so don't let that stop you.