# Background not displaying properly on iPad/Android

Tags: android, css, html, ipad

My website displays normally on most browsers, but I have two different problems on the iPad and the Android browsers.

1. Initially the webpage displays on a 1-1 scale, while I would like visitors to see the entire webpage.
2. The background doesn't show correctly. When I zoom out, only part of the background seems loaded.

I used:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

for the initial zoom and:

```
div.background {
    width: 100%;
    background: #ffffff url('../img/background_first.jpg') center top no-repeat;
}
```

for the background. I event tried to add:

```
-webkit-background-size: 1500px 1000px;
background-size: 1500px 1000px;
```

but the background problem (which is my main concern) remains. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you add a background image and on top of it everything else - thus this image will determine the size of the background for all?

Comment: try `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: @g00dy: nope, design limitation.

Comment: @Morpheus: Tried that too - nothing happened.

Comment: @Anax - does it still hapen when you change the orientation of the device?

Comment: @g00dy: Yes, it does.

Comment: Maybe this thread will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496505/differences-between-uiwebview-and-mobile-safari Hope so ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving your `.background` a fixed width.

100% width is 100% of the container, which in this case is `body`. On a mobile device, the `body` is much smaller than on a desktop, resulting in a cropped background image.

Also try to give a fixed width in your `meta viewport``

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=940, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: By changing the viewport as suggested, the webpage displays properly.